# C and pthreads: how can a mutex be referred to a particular variable?

Tags: c, locking, pthreads, global-variables, mutex

In [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/dotprod_mutex.c) code an example of the use of mutex is showed. In particular, the mutex is first declared before the `main`:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutexsum;
```

The particular variable to be "protected" by the mutex is `dotstr.sum` in the global structure `dotstr`: every thread writes on it after having acquired a `lock`. The correspondant code is:

```
pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexsum);
dotstr.sum += mysum;
printf("Thread %ld did %d to %d:  mysum=%f global sum=%f\n",offset,start,end,mysum,dotstr.sum);
pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexsum);
```

I have compiled the code and it obviously works, but I don't know mutexes very well. So, how can the program be aware that the "general" mutex `mutexsum` is applied just on the `dotstr.sum` variable?

There are many other global variables which can be locked. Why there is not an explicit relation in the code between the mutex `mutexsum` and the variable I want to lock, `dotstr.sum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (pthread) mutex isn't explicitly bound to a particular variable, it's just a general locking mechanism. It's up to you to make sure every action on that variable is properly surrounded by locks and unlocks.

Your program has a(n implicit) contract that only 1 thread may access `dotstr.sum`. The mutex helps you enforce it by making sure only 1 thread can have a lock on the mutex, but it won't force you to lock and unlock it everytime you do something with `dotstr.sum`.

Try, for example, commenting out the lock & unlock lines. The program will still compile and run, but the result may not be what you wanted it to be.

You can associate a mutex with anything, for example reading or writing from a file. But *you* must make sure that every access to the thing you want to lock is actually locked.